# How to remove duplicate rows if it is within a time period from the latest entry in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Hi all i have a table like this

| ID | result | grade | date | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | pass | 1 | 02/27 | 10 |
| A | fail | null | 02/25 | null |
| A | pass | 1 | 02/24 | 10 |
| A | pass | 1 | 02/23 | 10 |
| A | pass | 1 | 02/22 | 10 |
| A | pass | 1 | 02/21 | 10 |
| A | pass | 1 | 02/18 | 10 |
| A | pass | 1 | 02/16 | 10 |
| A | pass | 1 | 02/15 | 10 |
| A | pass | 1 | 02/03 | 10 |
| A | pass | 1 | 02/02 | 10 |

What I want is to remove the entry if result, grade and score are the same and the date is within 15 days of the latest entry. So the final table would look like this:

| ID | result | grade | date | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | pass | 1 | 02/27 | 10 |
| A | fail | null | 02/25 | null |
| A | pass | 1 | 02/03 | 10 |

Any methods of doing it in MySQL?

Comment: What is precise MySQL version? If there are 4 "duplicates" of 2022-01-01, 2022-01-11, 2022-01-21, and 2022-01-31 then what of them should be removed? Why the row for 02/03 and not for 02/02 is stored? *i have a table like this* Provide it as textual CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: If there are 4 duplicates of "2022-01-01, 2022-01-11, 2022-01-21 and 2022-01-31" then 2022-01-31 and 2022-01-11 is kept.

02/03 is the next latest entry out of 15 days time period from 02/27 and thus it will be the next latest entry and every duplicate within 15 days of 02/03 (i.e until 01/19) should be removed.

Comment: *02/03 is the next latest entry out of 15 days time period from 02/27 and thus it will be the next latest entry and every duplicate within 15 days of 02/03 (i.e until 01/19) should be removed.* If so then the row for 02/02 should present in the output too, is it? there is no reason to remove it...

Comment: And again: what is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: 02/02 should be removed because 02/03 would not be considered as a duplicate to 02/27 although every field is the same as the score lapses after 15 days.

I am using MySQL 8.0.23

Comment: ??? As I understand your need is: find the most upper 15-day range where more than one dup row is present, remove all dups except the row with the least date, exclude all these rows out of further consideration, repeat until all rows are processed. In this case all rows in a range 02/27..02/03 are processed as a group, 02/03 is stored, all another are ignored, all of them are removed from further consideration, and after this 02/02 is a row which forms single separate group and must be returned. You tell that this is not correct. Please formulate the criteria one more time, more detailed.